# Area between 2 curves

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the area bounded by the curves $x = y^2 - 2y$, $x = -1$, and $y=0$. I've sketched the graph and realize that I need to integrate with respect to $y$, but I'm stuck on whether I just need to integrate $y^2-2y$ with the bounds $0$ and $1$ or do I need to add in other factors?

Thanks!

Comment: Your title should be «area between two curves», no?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose that would be more appropriate!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to take the integral with respect to $y$, the area you seek is between the curves $x=-1$ and $x=y^2-2y$.  Your integral should be

$$\int\limits_0^1(y^2-2y+1)dy$$

Integrating with respect to $x$ is slightly more complicated.

$$x=y^2-2y=(y-1)^2-1$$
$$(y-1)^2=x+1$$
$$y=-\sqrt{x+1}+1$$

The negative square root gives us the lower half of the parabola.  So to integrate with respect to $x$, it's

$$\int\limits_{-1}^0(-\sqrt{x+1}+1)dx$$

Comment: I think you mean $y^2-2y{\color{red}+}1$ in the first integrand.

Comment: @Daryl oops.  Yes, $-(-1)$.  Fixing it now.